# Maintaining alignment of the vertical lines using \multicolumn for splitting cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, landscape

I am struggling with some big table in the landscape orientation. Problem is related to the vertical lines alignment direction in the following next rows. They mismatch. I want to attach, let's say reflectance for different angles in a manner as presented in the code (last column), i.e. one major column with subcolumns. For example `value1` and `value2` should correspond to the `30` subcolumn.

What am I doing wrong? is there any other useful package which I am not familiar with?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\title{Halp plax}

\begin{document}

\section{Some table}

\begin{table}[h]
\center
\resizebox{25cm}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \hline
        Próbka  &   Osnowa  &   Zbrojenie   &   Powłoka/kolor   &   Liczba impulsów &   Impuls przepalający    &  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}

        \multicolumn{4}{c}{Reflectivity (1060)} \\ \hline
        35 & 40 & 45 & 50 \\

        \end{tabular} \\ \hline

        i2&epoksyd&włókno węglowe&brak&10&10& 
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
        value1   &   value2   &   value3   & value4
        \end{tabular} \\ \hline

        i2&epoksyd&włókno węglowe&brak&10&10& 
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
        value2   &   value3   &   value4   & value5
        \end{tabular} \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}
    }
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: We don't care about "reflectance of different angles". You should really strip the contextual topic from future questions, and provide an example that just highlights the question at hand using plain English. For that you can use even letters for column headers. Do this next time you post a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first call to tabular you specify 10 columns but only end up using 7. So I removed those extra columns for clarity. I then added in the two `@{}` to remove the extra spacing created by the other tabular environments. If you do not include these the lines for the `\multicolumn` `\hline` will not extend wide enough

I then specified the width of the columns using the `p{width}` for all of the columns. Hopefully this is helpful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\title{Halp plax}

\begin{document}

\section{Some table}

\begin{table}[h]
\center
\resizebox{25cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}c@{}|}
\hline
    Prbka  &   Osnowa  &   Zbenie   &   Powor   &   Liczba impu &   Impuls pry    &  \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}}

    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Reflectivity (1060)} \\ 
    \hline
    35 & 40 & 45 & 50 \\

    \end{tabular} \\ \hline

    i2&epoksyd&wo we&brak&10&10& 
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}@{}}
    value1   &   value2   &   value3   & value4
    \end{tabular} \\ \hline

    i2&epod&wkno wwe&brk&10&10& 
    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}}
    value2   &   value3   &   value4   & value5
    \end{tabular} \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer.  Why don't you edit so as to also add an image of it?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Mostly because I don't know how to save the output as an image using TeXstudio or how most other people do it

Comment: I did it for you.

Comment: How can I center the text in subcolumns? i.e. 35,40,50, value1,value2. Right now it's aligned to the left

Comment: To center those you would need to create a new column type that we will call "C" that accepts one value as noted by the [1] below. The next curly braces define what the new column type does.  In this case we center the values and then call the original type p which takes the value of the argument, which is shown by the "#1" 
`\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}`

then replace all the places where `p{2cm}` occurs with `C{2cm}`